# Why does phpMyAdmin execute all queries with an apostrophe?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For example, if I use the GUI to perform an `INSERT`, the console will log the following execution:

[image]

Why does each item have apostrophes (*aside from `NULL`*)?

I know that I can do a  literal `INSERT` via terminal or PHP without the apostrophes, especially when referencing the table or columns (and [several](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm) [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) only apply apostrophes around the insert *values*, not table or column references). I know that this isn't exactly a, "help me question" but I am very curious if there's a reason behind this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those around values are *single quotes* - `'` and denote string values. Numbers should not be quoted if they are supposed to go to a numeric type column but in PhpMyAdmin every input field is textual by default so it probably just tries to stay safe with quoting the `'5'` too, MySQL can convert the type when needed.

The other type are *backticks* `` ` `` and it is a different character. MySQL uses it to quote identifiers (names of column, tables, indexes etc.). It is not needed when you use normal identifiers like `name` or `email` but it is needed for others:

- if you need to use a reserved word as an identifier - `` `insert` `` or `` `order` `` - not a good idea to create tables with such columns, but sometimes it already exists and you just need to query it.
- when you want to use complex names - `` `column named X` `` - again better not to name your columns like this, but it is often used for column aliases in selects

.

```
select col1 as `column 1`, col2 as `column with diacritics áéí` from table;
```

For PMA it is just simple to quote every identifier than to check if it is safe or not to go unquoted.